# sed command to match a file with patterns from another file

Tags: linux, sed, command, terminal

I have a file with number of lines with multiple text patterns,

let `pattern.txt`

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
```

I have another file where these patterns are present in a huge and complexly.

let `complex.txt`

Now I have to remove those lines from `complex.txt` which are exactly matched with the `pattern.txt`.

How to do this using `sed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to do it in-place, you could use the `--file` argument to `grep` (see the [`man` page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)).

That would give you something like:

```
grep --invert-match --file pattern.txt complext.txt > filtered.txt
```

to get the non-matching lines in a new file.

Comment: yeah thats working.thanks buddy... i hope there is nothing same like above with sed command....